# How to fix a squeaky electrical dryer

Tags: dryer, appliances, noise

[Here's a self-explanatory video of my squeaky electrical dryer that's driving everyone in household crazy.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl8bv.jpg)

The squeaking is clearly in sync with the rotation frequency, but that's all the insight I have at this point. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

The model of the dryer is FSE447GHSO.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably due to a bad or unlubricated drum roller. Look up the service manual for your dryer to get access to these rollers, but a generic diagram is below.

[image: Drum Roller]

Note that many dryer drums are not suspended from the center, but rather rest on a few rollers, front and back, beneath the drums. If there's friction in the roller, it might not contact the drum for the whole rotation but makes periodic, squeaky, contact.

Inspect the rollers. If the rubber wheel is deteriorated, a replacement roller and belt kit [might be about US$40, depending on dryer model,](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GGXKS7C) or look for just individual rollers. If the wheels look good, you could apply *one or two* drops of motor oil to the shafts. **Caution:** oil, lint and heat can lead to a *fire*, so vacuum the dryer thoroughly, and be sparing with the oil, which could also destroy the rubber belt.

If the dryer is more than a few years old, I'd suggest getting the correct roller replacement kit, rather than an individual roller, whatever the condition of the roller wheels, replacing only the bad one(s), keeping the rest until another breaks.

Comment: Some (many) dryer drums have a center-rear bearing and rest on cushions attached to the front shroud; they have no drum rollers. That center-rear bearing will squeak like that when it is worn. Also, the *idler wheel* is a completely different part that is associated with the drive belt...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it, if that's the case, can the bearing be replaced?

Comment: I've looked up the model of the dryer and it's a FSE447GHSO

Comment: Key is: "replacement roller and belt kit" - doesn't actually have to be a kit, could be rollers and belt separately. But definitely get a belt - they are designed to wear out and when you open up for rollers you might as well replace the belt at the same time. Belt by itself for your dryer is < $12 online.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it, thanks for corrections, applied above.

Answer (score 1):

The front door drawing is here.
Usually the squeak is due to the front drum glides (mounted the inside front) being worn.

https://www.partselect.com/Models/FSE447GHS0/Sections/P16D0023-FRNT-PNL-DOOR/?ModelID=1102488&ModelNum=FSE447GHS0&mfgModelNum=&ManufactureID=4&Selected=BV5VLVBJ&Position=4&mfg=Frigidaire&Type=Dryer&Mark=4

However, once you take off the front of the dryer, you should also check to see if the blower fan is loose -- that can also cause a squeak.  Finally, check the back bearing if the sound continues.

Comment: Yup, the model referenced uses an upper drum guide to support the front and a center-rear drum support bearing, **no drum support rollers**.